# Fetch request is not updating the state

Tags: reactjs, get, fetch

I have an react application connected to a database. Currently the app takes the database when it mounts and uses that to populate the state. The apps allows someone to post to the database. So far that works.

The issue is that I want the new posted content to be seen by the user. As it is the content only populates after I reload the page. I tried to repeat the coding in the componentDidMount() in a function that runs after the POST request, but for someone reason that is not working.

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        notes: [],
        folders: [],
        //noteID: 0,
        //folderID: 0
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        Promise.all([
          fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/notes`),
          fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/folders`)
        ])
          .then(([notesRes, foldersRes]) => {
            if (!notesRes.ok)
              return notesRes.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e))
            if (!foldersRes.ok)
              return foldersRes.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e))
    
            return Promise.all([
              notesRes.json(),
              foldersRes.json(),
            ])
          })
          .then(([notes, folders]) => {
            this.setState({ notes, folders })
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error({ error })
          })
      }

    pageReload = () =>{
        //console.log('pageReload ran');

        Promise.all([
            fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/notes`),
            fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/folders`)
          ])
            .then(([notesRes, foldersRes]) => {
              if (!notesRes.ok)
                return notesRes.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e))
              if (!foldersRes.ok)
                return foldersRes.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e))
      
              return Promise.all([
                notesRes.json(),
                foldersRes.json(),
              ])
            })
            .then(([notes, folders]) => {
              this.setState({ notes, folders })
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error({ error })
            })
    }
    
    folderSubmit = (f) => {
        //console.log("folderSubmit ran " + f);

        const newFolder = { "name" : f };

        const postfolder = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              },
            body: JSON.stringify(newFolder)
        };

        fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/folders`, postfolder).then(this.pageReload())

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not setting your state after post. see below  where you need to set your state.

```
folderSubmit = (f) => {
        //console.log("folderSubmit ran " + f);

        const newFolder = { "name" : f };

        const postfolder = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              },
            body: JSON.stringify(newFolder)
        };

        fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/folders`, postfolder)  
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState(data));

    }
```

Comment: That's weird, I thought setting the state in the function would work. I'm much closer to a solution. I just need to change the code you gave me a bit (It sets the object data as its own state. My object has an idea and name so it creates an id and name state instead of adding itself to the object array), but I think I can handle that.